# Cordova/Phonegap MessageBox

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using the following [plugin](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-messagebox) with Cordova/Phonegap

I am able to pop open a prompt window using this, I am having difficulty using the value entered by the user. I have the following code that creates the prompt -

```
window.plugins.messageBox.prompt({title: 'Title', message: 'Message'}, function(button, value){
    console.log(button, value)
});
```

This works perfectly and will output to the console the value entered. When I try to pass `value` to another function I get the following error -

```
Error in success callback: MessageBox2 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

Can anyway see where I am going wrong?

This is how I am trying to send the value to a function -

```
window.plugins.messageBox.prompt({title: 'Title', message: 'Message'}, function(button, value){
      outPutValue(button, value);
});

function outPutValue(button, value){
      alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `value` inside the callback function only? It is not defined outside the callback.

Comment: Can you post the code for the other function you're passing the value to?

Comment: I have added it to my question, its nothing fancy just trying to get it to work

Comment: The error is referencing MessgeBox2 not MessageBox. Where is MessageBox2 coming from?

Comment: its a weird one, if I place the console.log(value) in there after the function call it will output another error but it will be MessageBox3

Comment: MessageBox# is the success callback you provide in the call to prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem it would seem was the inclusion of an older version of MessageBox.js.... I have updated this to the version found in a sample folder on github and the problem has gone away.